# as_slice produces "not live enough" error

Tags: rust

I have following function:

```
    fn i_to_str(&self, i: int) -> &'a str {
        return i.to_string().as_slice();
    }
```

This code is producing `error: borrowed value does not live long enough` because of as_slice lifetime. Does anyone knows is there some workaround for this to make this possible?

Comment: A blog post of mine that explains what this sort of thing is all about: http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html

Answer (score 5):

You cannot return a slice from this function, because the `String` returned by `i.to_string()` would be freed/dropped when exiting the function, and the slice would refer to a freed string. You should return a `String` instead (return `i.to_string()` directly in this case), or a [`MaybeOwned`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/enum.MaybeOwned.html) if the method is defined by a trait and some implementations could reasonably return a slice.