# to_string() causes error "borrowed value does not live long enough"

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Why is `to_string()` causing `borrowed value does not live long enough` error? Example below:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo {
    id: Option<usize>,
    name: String
}

fn main() {

    let foos = getFoos();

    for foo in foos {
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("name", &foo.name);
        map.insert("id", &foo.id.unwrap().to_string());
    }

}

fn getFoos() -> Vec<Foo> {
    Vec::new()
}
```

Error:

```
src/main.rs:15:27: 15:54 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
src/main.rs:15         map.insert("id", &foo.id.unwrap().to_string());
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:13:38: 16:6 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 13:37...
src/main.rs:13         let mut map = HashMap::new();
src/main.rs:14         map.insert("name", &foo.name);
src/main.rs:15         map.insert("id", &foo.id.unwrap().to_string());
src/main.rs:16     }
src/main.rs:15:9: 15:56 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 15:8
src/main.rs:15         map.insert("id", &foo.id.unwrap().to_string());
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:15:9: 15:56 help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
src/main.rs:15         map.insert("id", &foo.id.unwrap().to_string());
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is compiler suggesting to create intermediate value? This error is confusing.

Comment: You are taking a reference to the value generated by `to_string`. Just remove the `&` and your code will work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b41ea549d5b4add70559827b7d41e58a&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return local String as a slice (&str)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str)

Comment: @ker I don't think it's a duplicate. Similar yes, but still different enough IMO :)

Comment: You probably don't want to insert references to strings into the map. Just remove all the & operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a `HashMap` that saves references to strings, namely `&String`. If we would annotate the type, it would look like this:

```
let mut map: HashMap<&str, &String> = HashMap::new();
```

This means that the map contains a lot of references to objects that live **somewhere else**. In your first insert, that works perfectly fine, since `foo.name` lives somewhere else, specifically in the object `foo`.

```
map.insert("name", &foo.name);
```

But your second insert has a problem: you want to reference a `String` object, that lives somewhere. `to_string()` creates a `String` which is returned by the function, but in your case it's just a temporary object. The object will be destroyed after the line is executed.

```
map.insert("id", &foo.id.unwrap().to_string());
```

The compiler is right: a `let` binding would solve the problem here.

```
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("name", &foo.name);
let id_string = foo.id.unwrap().to_string();
map.insert("id", &id_string);
```

This works fine in your small example, but it could be more complicated when you are working on something bigger. For example, if the `HashMap` would be defined outside of the loop, you would have a problem because the reference you insert into the map needs to live at least as long as the map itself.