# How do I fix this lifetime issue?

Tags: rust, hyper

In the code below, the `string` does not live long enough in the `Into<Body<'a>>` implementation for `RequestParameters<'a>`. I understand why, since `string` comes into scope inside of `into` and is no longer in scope after the method finishes, but `Body<'a>` will keep a reference to it.

At least, that's why I think `string` doesn't last long enough.

What I don't understand is how to structure this code to fix `string`'s lifetime.

The goal of this code is to make a HashMap (of `"a"` to `"b"` for example) into a string for the body of a POST request (`"?a=b"`, for example). If there is a better way to do this, please let me know, but what I would benefit a lot from is an understanding of how to fix this lifetime issue.

If I'm wrong about why `string` doesn't live long enough, please let me know, as well. I'm still trying to come to grips with the lifetime system in Rust, so figuring this out will help me a ton.

```
struct RequestParameters<'a> {
    map: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
}

impl<'a> From<HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>> for RequestParameters<'a> {
    fn from(map: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>) -> RequestParameters<'a> {
        RequestParameters { map: map }
    }
}

impl<'a> Into<Body<'a>> for RequestParameters<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> Body<'a> {
        let string = String::from("?") +
                     &self.map
            .iter()
            .map(|entry| format!("&{}={}", entry.0, entry.1))
            .collect::<String>()[1..];
        (&string).into()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut parameters = HashMap::new();
    parameters.insert("a", "b");
    let client = Client::new();
    client.post("https://google.com")
        .body(RequestParameters::from(parameters));
}
```

Comment: Your question essentially boils down to returning a `&str` from a function, which is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str). Please check it out, and if it does answer your question, I'll close this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As Vladimir's link points out, this is actually impossible. I changed my code to reflect this knowledge, and it now compiles.

```
struct RequestParameters<'a> {
    map: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
}

impl<'a> From<HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>> for RequestParameters<'a> {
    fn from(map: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>) -> RequestParameters<'a> {
        RequestParameters { map: map }
    }
}

impl<'a> RequestParameters<'a> {
    fn to_string(self) -> String {
        String::from("?") +
        &self.map.iter().map(|entry| format!("&{}={}", entry.0, entry.1)).collect::<String>()[1..]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut parameters = HashMap::new();
    parameters.insert("a", "b");
    let string_parameters = RequestParameters::from(parameters).to_string();
    let client = Client::new();
    client.post("https://google.com")
        .body(&string_parameters);
}
```

By creating the `String` before the `Client` is made I can borrow it with a longer lifetime than the `Client`, which fixes my issues.