# Remove single trailing newline from String without cloning

Tags: string, rust

I have written a function to prompt for input and return the result. In this version, the returned string includes a trailing newline from the user. I would like to return the input with that newline (and just that newline) removed:

```rust
fn read_with_prompt(prompt: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut input = String::new();
    print!("{}", prompt);
    stdout.lock().flush().unwrap();
    reader.read_line(&mut input)?;

    // TODO: Remove trailing newline if present
    Ok(input)
}
```

The reason for only removing the single trailing newline is that this function will also be used to prompt for a password (with appropriate use of [termios](https://crates.io/crates/termios) to stop echoing) and if someone's password has trailing whitespace, this should be preserved.

After much fussing about how to actually remove a single newline at the end of a string, I ended up using [`trim_right_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_right_matches). However that returns a `&str`. I tried using `Cow` to deal with this but the error still says that the `input` variable doesn't live long enough.

```rust
fn read_with_prompt<'a>(prompt: &str) -> io::Result<Cow<'a, str>> {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut input = String::new();
    print!("{}", prompt);
    stdout.lock().flush().unwrap();
    reader.read_line(&mut input)?;

    let mut trimmed = false;
    Ok(Cow::Borrowed(input.trim_right_matches(|c| {
        if !trimmed && c == '\n' {
            trimmed = true;
            true
        }
        else {
            false
        }
    })))
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `input`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:5
   |
13 |       Ok(Cow::Borrowed(input.trim_right_matches(|c| {
   |       ^                ----- `input` is borrowed here
   |  _____|
   | |
14 | |         if !trimmed && c == '\n' {
15 | |             trimmed = true;
16 | |             true
...  |
20 | |         }
21 | |     })))
   | |________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Based on [previous questions along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str) it seems this is not possible. Is the only option to allocate a new string that has the trailing newline removed? It seems there should be a way to trim the string without copying it (in C you'd just replace the `'\n'` with `'\0'`).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [`String::pop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.pop) or [`String::truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate):

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "hello\n".to_string();
    s.pop();
    assert_eq!("hello", &s);

    let mut s = "hello\n".to_string();
    let len = s.len();
    s.truncate(len - 1);
    assert_eq!("hello", &s);
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle \r\n newlines and also assumes the last character is a newline (which may be true in the question but not in the general case).

Answer (score 32):

A cross-platform way of stripping a single trailing newline without reallocating the string is this:

```
fn trim_newline(s: &mut String) {
    if s.ends_with('\n') {
        s.pop();
        if s.ends_with('\r') {
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

This will strip either `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` from the end of the string, but no additional whitespace.

Comment: Kind of annoying that we have to do this instead of it being baked into the language.. but I guess it does allow for OS optimization? I'm pretty new to all of this stuff.

Comment: If you want to iterate over the lines of a file or buffer, you can use `BufRead::lines`, which will [trim the newline characters for you](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.42.0/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#2397-2402). So the most common case is indeed covered by the standard library.

Answer (score 26):

## with [`strip_suffix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.strip_suffix)

This removes **one** trailing `\r\n` or `\n`:

```
fn strip_trailing_newline(input: &str) -> &str {
    input
        .strip_suffix("\r\n")
        .or(input.strip_suffix("\n"))
        .unwrap_or(input)
}
```

If there are multiple newlines, only the last one is stripped off.

If there is no newline at the end of the string, the string is unchanged.

Some tests:

```
#[test]
fn strip_newline_works(){
    assert_eq!(strip_trailing_newline("Test0\r\n\r\n"), "Test0\r\n");
    assert_eq!(strip_trailing_newline("Test1\r\n"), "Test1");
    assert_eq!(strip_trailing_newline("Test2\n"), "Test2");
    assert_eq!(strip_trailing_newline("Test3"), "Test3");
}
```

Comment: outstanding move with the tests!!

Answer (score 12):

A more generic solution than the accepted one, that works with any kind of line ending:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s = "hello\r\n".to_string();
    let len_withoutcrlf = s.trim_right().len();
    s.truncate(len_withoutcrlf);
    assert_eq!("hello", &s);
}
```

Comment: "If someone's password has trailing whitespace this should be preserved." However trim_right() will trim spaces too.

Comment: True. A better solution would be to pattern match on the last two characters/bytes and determine the truncation index. But that won't remove multiple newlines. The requirements aren't clear enough to decide on that.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you already have an owned `String`, you don't need a new allocation just to strip the trailing new line.

Here's a cross-platform example that removes **multiple** trailing `\r\n` or `\n` in place:

```rust
fn strip_trailing_nl(input: &mut String) {
    let new_len = input
        .char_indices()
        .rev()
        .find(|(_, c)| !matches!(c, '\n' | '\r'))
        .map_or(0, |(i, _)| i + 1);
    if new_len != input.len() {
        input.truncate(new_len);
    }
}
```

Now, let's test it (playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec2f6f60bdde32ccfeb8fa0c63a06f54):

```rust
#[test]
fn this_works() {
    let mut s = "\n".to_string();
    strip_trailing_nl(&mut s);
    assert_eq!(s, "");

    let mut s = "\r\n".to_string();
    strip_trailing_nl(&mut s);
    assert_eq!(s, "");

    let mut s = "Hello, World".to_string();
    strip_trailing_nl(&mut s);
    assert_eq!(s, "Hello, World");

    let mut s = "Hello, World\n".to_string();
    strip_trailing_nl(&mut s);
    assert_eq!(s, "Hello, World");

    let mut s = "Hello, World\r\n".to_string();
    strip_trailing_nl(&mut s);
    assert_eq!(s, "Hello, World");

    let mut s = "Hello, World\n\n\r\n\r\n".to_string();
    strip_trailing_nl(&mut s);
    assert_eq!(s, "Hello, World");

    let mut s = "".to_string();
    strip_trailing_nl(&mut s);
    assert_eq!(s, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just realized that the OP was looking to *not* make a copy of the string... so just making a note that this does in fact copy the string.  :(

I'm a Rust newbie, so I don't know when this function was introduced, but consider using the `String::lines` method. It looks like it should work cross-platform in a reliable way and in my local development, appeared to behave as the OP was looking for.

```rust
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter a line of text:");
    let mut buf = String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut buf).expect("Failed to read input.");
    let my_str = buf.lines()
        .next().expect("Could not read entry.");
    println!("You entered: [{}]", my_str);
}
```

Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.lines