# Concat String and convert them to &str

Tags: string, rust, concatenation

```
fn lyrics_more_bottles(song_template: &mut String, number: i32) {
    let mut template_partials = HashMap::new();
    let mut start_num = number.to_string();
    let mut remaining_num = (number - 1).to_string();

    template_partials.insert("start", start_num + " bottles");
    template_partials.insert("repeat", start_num + " bottles");
    template_partials.insert("remaining", remaining_num + " bottles");
    template_partials.insert("message", "Take one down and pass it around");

    resolve_template(song_template, template_partials);
}
```

I can't manage to convert those concatenated strings to a `&str`. I tried to put them into parentheses and call `.as_str()`. No luck on that.

I need to have a `HashMap<&str, &str>` so having a `String` is not an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you need to return the `&str` from the function, you are out of luck, see [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str).

If you *just* need to put the slices into a `HashMap` and pass it further down, you need to store the `String`s somewhere and fill the map with references into the `String`s:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn resolve_template(_: &mut String, _: HashMap<&str, &str>) {}

fn lyrics_more_bottles(song_template: &mut String, number: i32) {
    let mut start_num = number.to_string();
    let mut remaining_num = (number - 1).to_string();

    let start = start_num.clone() + " bottles";
    let repeat = start_num + " bottles";
    let remaining = remaining_num + " bottles";

    let mut template_partials = HashMap::new();

    template_partials.insert("start", &*start);
    template_partials.insert("repeat", &*repeat);
    template_partials.insert("remaining", &*remaining);
    template_partials.insert("message", "Take one down and pass it around");

    resolve_template(song_template, template_partials);
}

fn main() {}
```

We use `&*` to `Deref` the `String` to a `str` and then take another reference to end up at a `&str`.

Note that the `let mut template_partials` line has to be moved *after* the strings are created, otherwise when the strings are dropped, the map might contain references to invalid memory. Additionally, the `start_num` needs to be cloned as it's used twice.

---

Personally, I'd just use `format!` and use the same string twice instead of cloning and modifying it twice:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn resolve_template(_: &mut String, _: HashMap<&str, &str>) {}

fn lyrics_more_bottles(song_template: &mut String, number: i32) {
    let start_and_repeat = format!("{} bottles", number);
    let remaining = format!("{} bottles", number - 1);

    let mut template_partials = HashMap::new();

    template_partials.insert("start", &*start_and_repeat);
    template_partials.insert("repeat", &*start_and_repeat);
    template_partials.insert("remaining", &*remaining);
    template_partials.insert("message", "Take one down and pass it around");

    resolve_template(song_template, template_partials);
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Thanks! your format!() idea helped me out the most :D I totally forgot about that