# Can I create a binding with the type `Option<&str>`?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Can I create a binding with the type `Option<&str>`? Tiny non-working example:

```
fn main() {
    let a: Option<&str> = {
        Some(&{"a".to_string() + "b"}) // Let's say the string is not static
    };
}
```

This does not work, I need to add lifetime (or use a `Option<String>` without `&`). So how can I declare lifetime here? I know I can return a `Option<String>` and everything will be fine, but that's not what I want — I'm trying to understand some Rust mechanics. I can declare lifetime in a function, but don't know how to do this in a simple `let` binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "a".to_string() + "b";
    let a: Option<&str> = Some(&s);
}
```

The problem is not in creating a `Option<&str>`, it's that you are trying to take a reference to something that has gone out of scope. This is (a part of) the error message for the original code:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  |>         Some(&{"a".to_string() + "b"})
  |>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
```

See [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend lifetime of the string beyond `a`'s initializer expression by binding it to another name:

```
fn main() {
    let x: String = "a".to_string() + "b";
    let a: Option<&str> = {
        Some(&x)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to keep a reference to a value that does not live long enough, like the error says:

```
3 |>         Some(&{"a".to_string() + "b"}) // Let's say the string is not static
  |>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
```

You can have a bind of type `Option<&str>`, but the reference must live longer than the bind. In your example, you create a bind to the result string, an than take a reference to it:

```
fn main() {
    let x: String = "a".to_string() + "b";
    let a: Option<&str> = Some(&x);
}
```