# Can not return a Chars iterator because it "does not live long enough"

Tags: rust

I want to be able to assign a `Chars` iterator to a struct, whose `String` was created inside of the struct's "constructor" method.  How do I do this?

Code ([run it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Astr%3A%3AChars%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo%20%3D%20Foo%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Foo%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20chars%3A%20Chars%3C%27a%3E%0A%7D%0Aimpl%3C%27a%3E%20Foo%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new()%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20s%20%3D%20%22value%22.to_string()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%20%7B%20chars%3A%20s.chars()%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new();
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    chars: Chars<'a>
}
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let s = "value".to_string();
        Foo { chars: s.chars() }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: `s` does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:13:22
13 |>         Foo { chars: s.chars() }
   |>                      ^
note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 11:25...
  --> <anon>:11:26
11 |>     pub fn new() -> Self {
   |>                          ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 12:36
  --> <anon>:12:37
12 |>         let s = "value".to_string();
   |>
```

(In my real code, the constructor reads text from a file)

Comment: There are [**84 questions tagged rust**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+%22does+not+live+long+enough%22+is%3Aq) with the exact string `does not live long enough`. As a Stack Overflow user with 18k+ reputation, you should [know to show the research you have performed before asking the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/155423) to set a good example for people new to the site.

Comment: As Shepmaster said, there are already 84 questions explaining this very error message; could you explain what detail they lacked for your situation so that the answer can be tailored to your case instead of being a generic "that's just how it is"?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. `Chars` does not take ownership of the string, so once you go out of `Foo::new`, the string does not exist anymore. You need to store the string itself. `Chars` really is just a small utility type that's meant to be used on site, not stored somewhere to be used later.

Comment: See also [Return local String as a slice (&str)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str) - `Chars` [contains a slice](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.10.0/src/libcore/str/mod.rs#L326-L328).