# Unable to return a vector of string slices: borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: vector, rust, borrowing

I'm new to Rust and I'm having some trouble with the borrow checker. I don't understand why this code won't compile. Sorry if this is close to a previously answered question but I can't seem to find a solution in the other questions I've looked at.

I understand the similarity to [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423) but in that case it is just one string being returned and not enough for me to reason with my code in which I am trying to return a vector. From what I understand, I am trying to return references to `str` types that will go out of scope at the end of the function block and so should I be mapping that vector of `&str` into a vector of `String`? I am not so concerned about the performance effects of converting `&str` to `String`. First I'd just like to get it working.

This is the code, the error is in the `lex` function.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::env;

fn open(mut s: &mut String, filename: &String) {
    let mut f = match File::open(&filename) {
        Err(_) => panic!("Couldn't open file"),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };
    match f.read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Err(_) => panic!("Couldn't read file"),
        Ok(_) => println!("File read successfully"),
    };

}

fn lex(s: &String) -> Vec<&str> {
    let token_string: String = s.replace("(", " ( ")
        .replace(")", " ) ");

    let token_list: Vec<&str> = token_string.split_whitespace()
        .collect();
    token_list
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() < 2 {
        panic!("Please provide a filename");
    } else {
        let ref filename = args[1];

        let mut s = String::new();
        open(&mut s, filename);
        let token_list: Vec<&str> = lex(&s);
        println!("{:?}", token_list);
    }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
        self.0.borrow().values.get(idx)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 23:54...
    pub fn value(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<&Value> {
                                                      ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 23:54
    pub fn value(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<&Value> {
                                                      ^
```

I'm finding it hard to reason with this code because with my level of experience with Rust I can't visualise the lifetimes of these variables. Any help would be appreciated as I've spent an hour or two trying to figure this out.

Comment: have you looked at any of the other "x does not live long enough" stackoverflow questions? You are creating a new `String` in the `lex` function and then trying to return references into that `String`, even though that `String` does not outlive the `lex` function, so your references would point into the void.

Comment: Would I have to define the string outside the function and pass in a mutable reference or is there a way to extend the lifetime of a string defined inside the function so that it can outlive the `lex` function?

Comment: you can't extend a lifetime, ever. I have a solution to your problem, but you need to change your question if you don't want it marked as a duplicate. It should address why it is different than all the other questions that ask how to return references to an owned object.

Comment: The duplicate will be http://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423; but you can have a bit of time to make it different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're allocating a new `String` (`token_string`) inside the `lex` function and then returning an array of references to it, but `token_string` will get dropped (and the memory freed) as soon as it falls out of scope at the end of the function.

```
fn lex(s: &String) -> Vec<&str> {
    let token_string: String = s.replace("(", " ( ") // <-- new String allocated 
        .replace(")", " ) "); 

    let token_list: Vec<&str> = token_string.split_whitespace()
        .collect();
    token_list // <-- this is just an array of wide pointers into token_string
} // <-- token_string gets freed here, so the returned pointers
  //     would be pointing to memory that's already been dropped!
```

There's a couple of ways to address this. One would be to force the caller of `lex` to pass in the buffer that you want to use to collect into. This would change the signature to `fn lex<'a>(input: &String, buffer: &'a mut String) -> Vec<&'a str>` This signature would specify that the lifetimes of the returned `&str`s will be at least as long as the lifetime of the buffer that's passed in.

Another way would be to just return a `Vec<String>` instead of `Vec<&str>` if you can tolerate the extra allocations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That makes a lot of sense now.