# Problems with lifetimes on recursive trait functions

Tags: rust, mergesort, lifetime

I am having a hard time converting my standalone `merge_sort` function into a trait for `Vec<T>`. It seems I am running into lifetime errors with the way the merge sort algorithm works.

I have tried specifying the lifetimes in the function and trait declarations but it still is giving me a similar error.

My research on lifetimes includes...

- Effective Rust
- The Rust book
- Several YouTube videos on lifetimes
- Most questions on Stack Overflow regarding lifetimes

Here is the code

```
trait MergeSortable<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self);
    fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T>;
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> MergeSortable<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self) {
        if self.len() <= 1 {
            return;
        }
        let mid = self.len() / 2;
        let mut left = self[..mid].to_vec();
        left.merge_sort();
        let mut right = self[mid..].to_vec();
        right.merge_sort();
        self = self._merge(&mut left, &mut right);
    }

    fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
        if left.len() == 0 {
            return right;
        }
        if right.len() == 0 {
            return left;
        }
        if left[0] < right[0] {
            let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
            v.push(left[0].clone());
            v.extend_from_slice(&self._merge(&mut left[1..].to_vec().clone(), &mut right.clone())[..]);
            return &mut v;
        }
        let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
        v.push(right[0].clone());
        v.extend_from_slice(&self._merge(&mut left.clone(), &mut right[1..].to_vec().clone())[..]);
        return &mut v;
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b73494e356a103cecb8d65eb80f7d5ce&version=stable&backtrace=0))

And the errors:

```
error: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content... [E0312]
  --> <anon>:27:20
   |>
27 |>             return left;
   |>                    ^^^^
note: ...the reference is valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 22:75...
  --> <anon>:22:76
   |>
22 |>     fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
   |>                                                                            ^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the block at 22:75
  --> <anon>:22:76
   |>
22 |>     fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
   |>                                                                            ^

error: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content... [E0312]
  --> <anon>:24:20
   |>
24 |>             return right;
   |>                    ^^^^^
note: ...the reference is valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 22:75...
  --> <anon>:22:76
   |>
22 |>     fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
   |>                                                                            ^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the block at 22:75
  --> <anon>:22:76
   |>
22 |>     fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
   |>                                                                            ^
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn _merge<'a, 'b>(&'a self, left: &'a mut Vec<T>, right: &'b mut Vec<T>)
 -> &mut Vec<T>
  --> <anon>:22:5
   |>
22 |>     fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
   |>     ^
```

Comment: @Shepmaster: The code has many issues, and this is just one of them...

Comment: Answerers may also be interested in [giving OP a code review of this and other sort algorithms](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/141605/32521).

Comment: @electrometro that was directed more at me than at you ^_^. I tend to have a heavy hand with marking questions as duplicates; that was a way of telling me that such a duplicate would not serve useful.

Comment: @Shepmaster I am just hangry and taking everything to the extreme the first read though. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_merge` doesn't actually need its `self` argument. Let's remove it:

```
use std::cmp::Ord;
use std::clone::Clone;

trait MergeSortable<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self);
    fn _merge(left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T>;
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> MergeSortable<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self) {
        if self.len() <= 1 {
            return;
        }
        let mid = self.len() / 2;
        let mut left = self[..mid].to_vec();
        left.merge_sort();
        let mut right = self[mid..].to_vec();
        right.merge_sort();
        self = Self::_merge(&mut left, &mut right);
    }

    fn _merge(left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
        if left.len() == 0 {
            return {right};
        }
        if right.len() == 0 {
            return {left};
        }
        if left[0] < right[0] {
            let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
            v.push(left[0].clone());
            v.extend_from_slice(&Self::_merge(&mut left[1..].to_vec().clone(), &mut right.clone())[..]);
            return &mut v;
        }
        let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
        v.push(right[0].clone());
        v.extend_from_slice(&Self::_merge(&mut left.clone(), &mut right[1..].to_vec().clone())[..]);
        return &mut v;
    }
}
```

Now we're getting a different error:

```
error: missing lifetime specifier [--explain E0106]
 --> <anon>:6:57
  |>
6 |>     fn _merge(left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T>;
  |>                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from `left` or `right`

error: missing lifetime specifier [--explain E0106]
  --> <anon>:22:57
   |>
22 |>     fn _merge(left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T> {
   |>                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from `left` or `right`
```

And this helps us understand the first problem: when there's a `self` parameter and the return value is a reference, the compiler will infer that the lifetime of the returned reference is linked to `self`. That's not the case at all here! By removing the `self` parameter, the compiler is faced with two arguments that are references, and the current elision rules make it so that you *must* specify an explicit lifetime.

So, let's do that!

```
use std::cmp::Ord;
use std::clone::Clone;

trait MergeSortable<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self);
    fn _merge<'a>(left: &'a mut Vec<T>, right: &'a mut Vec<T>) -> &'a mut Vec<T>;
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> MergeSortable<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self) {
        if self.len() <= 1 {
            return;
        }
        let mid = self.len() / 2;
        let mut left = self[..mid].to_vec();
        left.merge_sort();
        let mut right = self[mid..].to_vec();
        right.merge_sort();
        self = Self::_merge(&mut left, &mut right);
    }

    fn _merge<'a>(left: &'a mut Vec<T>, right: &'a mut Vec<T>) -> &'a mut Vec<T> {
        if left.len() == 0 {
            return right;
        }
        if right.len() == 0 {
            return left;
        }
        if left[0] < right[0] {
            let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
            v.push(left[0].clone());
            v.extend_from_slice(&Self::_merge(&mut left[1..].to_vec().clone(), &mut right.clone())[..]);
            return &mut v;
        }
        let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
        v.push(right[0].clone());
        v.extend_from_slice(&Self::_merge(&mut left.clone(), &mut right[1..].to_vec().clone())[..]);
        return &mut v;
    }
}
```

But now, we're getting more errors. Let's focus on this one:

```
error: `v` does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:33:25
   |>
33 |>             return &mut v;
   |>                         ^
note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 22:81...
  --> <anon>:22:82
   |>
22 |>     fn _merge<'a>(left: &'a mut Vec<T>, right: &'a mut Vec<T>) -> &'a mut Vec<T> {
```

You're trying to return a reference to a local variable. You can't do that: you must return the value itself, just like you were doing in your original function. See [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423) for more information.

Perhaps one trick you didn't know about is that you can replace the value behind a reference by assigning to its dereference (`*self = new_value`).

```
use std::cmp::Ord;
use std::clone::Clone;

trait MergeSortable<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self);
    fn _merge(left: Vec<T>, right: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>;
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> MergeSortable<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn merge_sort(&mut self) {
        if self.len() <= 1 {
            return;
        }
        let mid = self.len() / 2;
        let mut left = self[..mid].to_vec();
        left.merge_sort();
        let mut right = self[mid..].to_vec();
        right.merge_sort();
        *self = Self::_merge(left, right);
    }

    fn _merge(left: Vec<T>, right: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
        if left.len() == 0 {
            return right;
        }
        if right.len() == 0 {
            return left;
        }
        if left[0] < right[0] {
            let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
            v.push(left[0].clone());
            v.extend_from_slice(&Self::_merge(left[1..].to_vec(), right)[..]);
            return v;
        }
        let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
        v.push(right[0].clone());
        v.extend_from_slice(&Self::_merge(left, right[1..].to_vec())[..]);
        return v;
    }
}
```

I would also consider moving `_merge` out of the trait and into a free function, so that you don't have to write `Self::_merge` to call it.

Comment: Nice! This is full of hidden tricks I couldn't figure out after about an hour of messing with the lifetimes. So by removing self it makes it a static function, correct?

Comment: Yes, removing `self` makes `_merge` a static function, but as it's in a trait, it's still polymorphic, so we need to write `Self::` or `MergeSortable::` before its name when calling it, so that the compiler knows which implementation we want to call.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this worked before you converted it to a trait version. The problem is with the the signature of `_merge`:

```
fn _merge(&self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<T>;
```

That signature is actually a shorthand for:

```
fn _merge<'a>(&'a self, left: &mut Vec<T>, right: &mut Vec<T>) -> &'a mut Vec<T>;
```

That means, that the returned value must be a borrow from `self`. In your case, that's totally not true, as you either return `left` or `right`, or a totally new vector (and you [can't return a reference to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423)). The easiest way to fix it would be to return just `Vec<T>`. Or if you want to save a `.clone()` when returning `left` or `right`, you can return a [`Cow<[T]>`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) (I don't think it's worth it though).

Also, I think that `_merge` doesn't really belong to a trait, you're not even using `self` there. I'd make it just a function.

Comment: It was a [free function before](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/141605/32521).