# Is there a way to avoid cloning when converting a PathBuf to a String?

Tags: string, rust, std, ownership-semantics

I need to simply (and dangerously - error handling omitted for brevity) get the current executable name. I made it work, but my function converts a `&str` to `String` only to call `as_str()` on it later for pattern matching.

```
fn binary_name() -> String {
    std::env::current_exe().unwrap().file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string()
}
```

As I understand it, `std::env::current_exe()` gives me ownership of the `PathBuf` which I could transfer by returning it. As it stands, I borrow it to convert it to `&str`. From there, the only way to return the string is to clone it before the `PathBuf` is dropped.

Is there any way to avoid this `&OsStr -> &str -> String -> &str` cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid cloning when converting a `PathBuf` to a `String`?

Absolutely. However, that's not what you are doing. You are taking a **part** of the `PathBuf` via `file_name` and converting that. You cannot take ownership of a part of a string.

If you weren't taking a subset, then converting an entire `PathBuf` can be done by converting to an `OsString` and then to a `String`. Here, I ignore the specific errors and just return success or failure:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn exe_name() -> Option<String> {
    std::env::current_exe()
        .ok()
        .map(PathBuf::into_os_string)
        .and_then(|exe| exe.into_string().ok())
}
```

> Is there any way to avoid this `&OsStr -> &str -> String -> &str` cycle?

No, because you are creating the `String` (or `OsString` or `PathBuf`, whichever holds ownership depending on the variant of code) inside your method. Check out [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423) for why you cannot return a reference to a stack-allocated item (including a string).

As stated in that Q&A, if you want to have references, the thing owning the data has to outlive the references:

```
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn binary_name(path: &Path) -> Option<&str> {
    path.file_name().and_then(OsStr::to_str)
}

fn main() {
    let exe = env::current_exe().ok();
    match exe.as_ref().and_then(|e| binary_name(e)) {
        Some("cat") => println!("Called as cat"),
        Some("dog") => println!("Called as dog"),
        Some(other) => println!("Why did you call me {}?", other),
        None => println!("Not able to figure out what I was called as"),
    }
}
```

---

Your original code can be written to not crash on errors easily enough

```
fn binary_name() -> Option<String> {
    let exe = std::env::current_exe();
    exe.ok()
        .as_ref()
        .and_then(|p| p.file_name())
        .and_then(|s| s.to_str())
        .map(String::from)
}
```

Comment: Neat. I thought there would be no way without moving ownership outside of the function. Just my C ways shining through.

Comment: @mgoszcz2 I'm not sure I'm following you - in the first and third examples, new data is allocated, and in the second example, ownership *is* outside of the function.

Comment: No it's just in C I would just return a pointer to `argv[0] + offset`

Comment: @mgoszcz2 ah, yes, that's closest to the second example. `argv[0]`, in the name of `exe`, is passed into the function, and then the string is offset and terminated and returned, just with more error handling.