# Why can't I map Path::new over the std::env::args iterator?

Tags: iterator, rust

This works:

```
let paths: Vec<String> = args.collect();
let paths = paths.iter().map(|f| std::path::Path::new(&f));
```

This doesn't work:

```
let paths = ::std::env::args().map(|f| std::path::Path::new(&f));
```

```
error[E0597]: `f` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:2:66
  |
2 |     let paths = ::std::env::args().map(|f| std::path::Path::new(&f));
  |                                                                  ^-- borrowed value needs to live until here
  |                                                                  ||
  |                                                                  |`f` dropped here while still borrowed
  |                                                                  borrowed value does not live long enough
```

Why do I need to `collect` the `args` iterator into a vector just to produce another iterator? Why can't I produce one iterator directly from another?

Comment: You most likely want `PathBuf`, not `Path`.

Comment: `PathBuf` is mutable. I don't need mutability here. Why do you think I need `PathBuf`?

Answer (score 4):

The [`Args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html) iterator returns values of type `String`. When you [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) over an iterator, the closure is given ownership of each value.

The code that doesn't work attempts to take a reference to the `String`, but that string will go out of scope at the end of the closure. This is disallowed as discussed in [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423).

The code that does work is not iterating over `String`s but `&String`s; see [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423). Thus there's nothing to go out of scope in the closure and returning a reference from the closure is fine.

The correct solution is to transfer ownership of the `String`'s data to a new type. [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) is the appropriate choice. `PathBuf` is to `&Path` as `String` is to `&str`:

```
let paths = ::std::env::args().map(std::path::PathBuf::from);
```

> `PathBuf` is mutable. I don't need mutability here. Why do you think I need `PathBuf`?

You are confused about how mutability works in Rust. Go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), especially the chapter on [Variables and Mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html).

Types in Rust are not mutable or immutable by themselves. Mutability is a property *of the variable binding*:

```
let buf = std::path::PathBuf::new();
buf.push("home");
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable local variable `buf` as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
2 |     let buf = std::path::PathBuf::new();
  |         --- consider changing this to `mut buf`
3 |     buf.push("home");
  |     ^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```