# Why is std::borrow::Cow apparently required when mapping over strings with a Regex?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a code parser in a `Parser` struct. I am exposing a pub method `lines` to iterate over the lines of code with the comments removed. I want to return a `Box<Iterator>`

```
extern crate regex; // 1.0.5

use regex::Regex;

pub struct Parser {
    code: String,
}

static comment: Regex = Regex::new(r"//.*$").unwrap();

impl Parser {
    pub fn new(code: String) -> Parser {
        Parser { code }
    }

    pub fn lines(&self) -> Box<Iterator<Item = &str>> {
        let lines = self
            .code
            .split("\n")
            .map(|line| comment.replace_all(line, ""));
        Box::new(lines)
    }
}
```

However, the compiler is giving *this error:*

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/lib.rs:20:18: 20:54] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output == &str`
  --> src/lib.rs:21:9
   |
21 |         Box::new(lines)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::borrow::Cow`, found &str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::borrow::Cow<'_, str>`
              found type `&str`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::iter::Map<std::str::Split<'_, &str>, [closure@src/lib.rs:20:18: 20:54]>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`
```

It wants me to use `std::borrow::Cow`, but I can't find anything in [the `Map` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html#impl-Iterator) mentioning this requirement. Why is this necessary? Can I avoid it?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `static COMMENT` instead, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is highly recommended to read the documentation for *all* of the types and methods you are using. For example, [`Regex::replace_all`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.0.5/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace_all) is documented as:

```
pub fn replace_all<'t, R: Replacer>(
    &self, 
    text: &'t str, 
    rep: R
) -> Cow<'t, str>
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's where the `Cow` comes from.

It is impossible to return an iterator of `&str`s once you have allocated new strings; you will need to pick a new iterator type. Something like this seems possible, but since your code doesn't compile for reasons other than this lifetime issue, I cannot easily test it.

```
pub fn lines<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Cow<'a, str>> + 'a>
```

See also:

- [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation regarding the docs. I'm coming over from JS, which seldom has its objects well documented. So I'm used to just introspecting in a REPL to find out what fields the objects have. I sort of brought that habit with me into Rust. But now, I've been developing my Rust with the docs close at hand from now on, and it's a much better experience! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution for my case.

`replace_all` is not a good method for this use case. I just want to remove comments. I never need to insert anything into the string. If so, I should just be able to work with string slices. No need for the `Cow` type introduced by `replace_all`. Here is how I did it instead.

```
impl Parser {
    pub fn lines<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a str> + 'a> {
        let lines = self.code
            .lines()
            .map(|line| { line.split("//").next().unwrap() })
            .map(|line| line.trim())
            .filter(|line| line.len() > 0);

        Box::new(lines)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already discovered, [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) comes from [`Regex::replace_all`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.0.5/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace_all)

In your case, there is a *very dangerous and discouraged* way to get an iterator of `&str`:

```
extern crate regex; // 1.0.5

use regex::Regex;
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub struct Parser {
    code: String,
}

impl Parser {
    pub fn new(code: String) -> Parser {
        Parser { code }
    }

    pub fn lines<'a>(&'a self, comment: Regex) -> Box<Iterator<Item = &'a str> + 'a> {
        let lines = self
            .code
            .split("\n")
            .map(move |line| comment.replace_all(line, ""))
            .map(|cow| match cow {
                Cow::Borrowed(sref) => sref,
                Cow::Owned(_) => panic!("I hope never to be here"),
            });
        Box::new(lines)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let comment: Regex = Regex::new(r"//.*$").unwrap();

    let p = Parser::new("hello\nworld".to_string());

    for item in p.lines(comment) {
        println!("{:?}", item);
    }
}
```

This works because there are no `Cow`s that allocate strings.

A better way could be to return an iterator of `String`s:

```
pub fn lines<'a>(&'a self, comment: Regex) -> Box<Iterator<Item = String> + 'a> {
    let lines = self
        .code
        .split("\n")
        .map(move |line| comment.replace_all(line, ""))
        .map(|cow| cow.into_owned());

    Box::new(lines)
}
```

Comment: To be blunt, this is a *terrible* suggestion. If the `replace_all` call never needs to be run (and thus never needs to return `Cow::Owned`), then *it shouldn't be there*. Presumably OP actually does need to remove comments for some reason, thus this will always panic. It's also not "dangerous" at all.

Comment: I also disagree that returning `String`s is universally "better"; now you have to re-allocate for every line, which seems like a big waste of performance.

Comment: Indeed, I only need to remove comments. Copies should not be necessary. I think `replace_all` was a poor method choice on my part. I posted an answer for a much better approach.