# Scope of 'let' with shadowing and String -> &str conversion

Tags: rust

With the following code, I tried to return &str of temperature of user input, but in vain. Then, I am trying to return f32, but still struggle...

Q1. The reason I am getting the error at the bottom is because the scope of '`let temp = String::new();`' still persists, even I 'shadow' it later by '`let temp = temp.trim().parse::<f32>();`' within the loop?

Q2. How can I rewrite the code so that it returns &str?

```
fn gettemp() -> f32 {
    let temp = String::new();

    loop {
        println!("What is your temperature?");

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp).expect("Failed to read the line");

        let temp = temp.trim().parse::<f32>();

        if !temp.is_ok() {
            println!("Not a number!");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    temp
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:70:5
   |
49 | fn gettemp() -> f32 {
   |                 --- expected `f32` because of return type
...
70 |     temp
   |     ^^^^ expected f32, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected type `f32`
              found type `std::string::String`
```

Comment: The second question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/1233251). You might want to stick to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1 - nope, that's not how shadowing works. Let's look at your code with comments.

```rust
fn gettemp() -> f32 {
    let temp = String::new(); // Outer

    loop {
        // There's no inner temp at this point, even in the second
        // loop pass, etc.

        println!("What is your temperature?");

        // Here temp refers to the outer one (outside of the loop)
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp).expect("Failed to read the line");

        // Shadowed temp = let's call it inner temp
        let temp = temp.trim().parse::<f32>();
        //    ^      ^
        //    |      |- Outer temp
        //    |- New inner temp

        // temp refers to inner temp
        if !temp.is_ok() {
            println!("Not a number!");
        } else {
            // Inner temp goes out of scope
            break;
        }

        // Inner temp goes out of scope
    }

    // Here temp refers to outer one (String)
    temp
}
```

---

A2 - you can't return `&str`. @E_net4 posted a link to the answer why. However, you can return `String`. You can do something like this nn case you'd like to have a validated `String`:

```rust
fn gettemp() -> String {
    loop {
        println!("What is your temperature?");

        let mut temp = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut temp)
            .expect("Failed to read the line");

        let trimmed = temp.trim();

        match trimmed.parse::<f32>() {
            Ok(_) => return trimmed.to_string(),
            Err(_) => println!("Not a number!"),
        };
    }
}
```

---

I see couple of another problems in your code.

```rust
let temp = String::new();
```

Should be `let mut temp`, because you'd like to borrow mutable reference later (`&mut temp` in the `read_line` call).

Another issue is the `loop` & `read_line`. `read_line` appends to the `String`. Run this code ...

```rust
let mut temp = "foo".to_string();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp).unwrap();
println!("->{}<-", temp);
```

... and enter `10` for example. You'll see following output ...

```
->foo10
<-
```

... which is not what you want. I'd rewrite `gettemp()` in this way:

```rust
fn gettemp() -> f32 {
    loop {
        println!("What is your temperature?");

        let mut temp = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut temp)
            .expect("Failed to read the line");

        match temp.trim().parse() {
            Ok(temp) => return temp,
            Err(_) => println!("Not a number!"),
        };
    }
}
```

IMHO explicit `return temp` is much cleaner & readable (compared to suggested break out of the loop with a value).

---

A3 - Why we don't need to explicitly state `<f32>` in `temp.trim().parse()`

It's inferred by the compiler.

```rust
fn gettemp() -> f32 { // 1. f32 is return type
    loop {
        println!("What is your temperature?");

        let mut temp = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut temp)
            .expect("Failed to read the line");

        match temp.trim().parse() {
        // 4. parse signature is pub fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, ...>
        //    compiler knows it must be Result<f32, ...>
        //    Result<f32, ...> = Result<F, ...> => F = f32
        //    F was inferred and there's no need to explicitly state it
            Ok(temp) => return temp,
            //  |                |
            //  |      2. return type is f32, temp must be f32
            //  |
            //  | 3. temp must be f32, the parse result must be Result<f32, ...>            
            Err(_) => println!("Not a number!"),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is why we don't need to explicitly state <f32> in 'temp.trim().parse()' I looked at documentation that states "Parses this string slice into another type." Can you elaborate on this, please?

Comment: @JuliaO I updated my answer. Check the _A3 - Why we don't need to explicitly state <f32> in temp.trim().parse()_ at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1, you can `break` out of the loop with a value:

```
fn gettemp() -> f32 {
    let mut temp = String::new();

    loop {
        println!("What is your temperature?");

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp).expect("Failed to read the line");

        let temp = temp.trim().parse::<f32>();

        if !temp.is_ok() {
            println!("Not a number!");
        } else {
            break temp.unwrap() // yield value when breaking out of loop
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the whole loop's value is the thing you passed along with `break`.

Regarding question 2, I am not sure if you really want to do this, because `&str` is a borrowed type. I think you want to return an `String` in this case which owns the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @phimuemue. What is the difference between 'return' and 'break' with return value? Either makes any difference?

Comment: @JuliaO `return` returns from the whole function, while `break` prematurely exits a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, `loop { ... }` creates a new scope. The scope of the second `temp` starts where it's defined and ends when `loop` ends. See the following example:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    {
        let a = 2;
        println!("{}", a);
    }
    println!("{}", a);
}
```

This prints 2, 1。

If you want to return a string, use (the code is fixed according to the comment below):

```
fn gettemp() -> String {
    loop {
        let mut temp = String::new();
        println!("What is your temperature?");
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp).expect("Failed to read the line");
        temp = temp.trim().to_string();
        match temp.parse::<f32>() {
            Err(_) => println!("Not a number!"),
            _ => return temp,
        }
    }
}
```

`&str` is a borrowed reference. You cannot return a borrowed reference to a local variable which will be released when the function returns.

Comment: It's wrong, see my answer. First - `read_line` appends to the `temp` - try to enter `a<enter>10<enter>`. `temp` will contain `a\n10\n` and this `loop` will never end. Second - you're matching `temp.trim().parse::<f32>()` result and then you're returing untrimmed `temp` - try to enter `10<enter>` and the return value will be `"10\n"`, not `"10"`, which isn't probably what you want.

Comment: @zrzka you're right. I didn't realize read_line appends to the buffer.