# Is it possible to build a HashMap of &str referencing environment variables?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a read-only map of environment variables.

```
fn os_env_hashmap() -> HashMap<&'static str, &'static str> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    use std::env;
    for (key,val) in env::vars_os() {
        let k = key.to_str();
        if k.is_none() { continue } 
        let v = val.to_str();
        if v.is_none() { continue }
        k.unwrap();
        //map.insert( k.unwrap(), v.unwrap() );
    }
    return map;
}
```

Can't seem to uncomment the "insert" line near the bottom without compiler errors about key,val,k, and v being local.

I *might* be able to fix the compiler error by using String instead of str, but str seems perfect for a read-only result.

Feel free to suggest a more idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: You said it yourself: you should store owned types. It does not matter that the result is "read-only", the data has to live somewhere. You are trying to return `HashMap<&'static str, &'static str>`, but `key` and `val` only live for one iteration of the loop, so references to them can not be `'static`.

Comment: To add to @justinas comment: `'static` has absolutely nothing to do with “heap” v. “stack”.

Comment: So far, I haven't been able to figure out how to use String to solve this problem either. Tried .to_owned() and, for example, "let k:String=".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is unfortunately not straightforward using only the facilities of the Rust standard library.

If `env::vars_os()` returned an iterator over `&'static OsStr` instead of `OsString`, this would be trivial. Unfortunately, not all platforms allow creating an `&OsStr` to the contents of an environment variable. In particular, on Windows, the native encoding is UTF-16 but the encoding needed by `OsStr` is [WTF-8](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/). For this reason, there really *is* no `OsStr` anywhere you could take a reference to, until you create an `OsString` by iterating over `env::vars_os()`.

The simplest thing, as the question comments mention, is to return owned `String`s:

```
fn os_env_hashmap() -> HashMap<String, String> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    use std::env;
    for (key, val) in env::vars_os() {
        // Use pattern bindings instead of testing .is_some() followed by .unwrap()
        if let (Ok(k), Ok(v)) = (key.into_string(), val.into_string()) {
            map.insert(k, v);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

The result is not "read-only", but it is not shared, so you cannot cause data races or other weird bugs by mutating it.

### See also

- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function)
- [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str)

Comment: Not only did you answer with working code, you explained why it works, and -- amazingly -- you worded your explanation in a way that did not hurt my feelings! Fantastic.