# How does assigning variables with references work with rust when assignment occurs within a for loop?

Tags: rust

I only just started learning rust and don't quite understand the referencing system that rust uses yet. In the following function, I am trying to write code for FizzBuzz that assigns result a `&str` depending on the lowest common multiple of a `u32` in a range.

```
fn fizzbuzz(last_num: u32) {
    for i in 1..last_num+1 {
        let result = if i % 15 == 0 {
            "FizzBuzz"
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            "Fizz"
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            "Buzz"
        } else {
            &i.to_string()[..]
        };
        println!("{}", result);
    }
}
```

in my else clause, I get the following error:

```
11 |           } else if i % 5 == 0 {
   |  ________________-
12 | |             "Buzz"
13 | |         } else {
14 | |             &i.to_string()[..]
   | |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use       
15 | |         };
   | |         -
   | |         |
   | |_________temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |           borrow later used here
```

From what I understand so far about rust, this shouldn't be an issue because the `&i` reference is being used before the end of the scope where `i` is freed from memory.

What exactly am I doing wrong, and what is the fix?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str). You need to return an owned string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `&i` reference, but created something new as a temporary variable  which is `i.to_string()` (String type) then it's being used to create str (primitive type) referring the String type which later is being destroyed because it's temporary. Meaning you're calling something inexistent. and `String` and `str` are different, [you can see the explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str?rq=1).

the easiest way to fix this is to use `String` instead:

```
fn fizzbuzz(last_num: u32) {
    for i in 1..last_num+1 {
        let result: String = if i % 15 == 0 {
            String::from("FizzBuzz")
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            String::from("Fizz")
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            String::from("Buzz")
        } else {
            i.to_string()
        };
        println!("{}", result);
    }
}
```

but if you want to stay using the `str` type, you can do it like below:

```
fn fizzbuzz(last_num: u32) {
    for i in 1..last_num+1 {
        let wont_be_destroyed: String = i.to_string(); 
        let mut result = &wont_be_destroyed[..];
        if i % 15 == 0 {
            result = &"FizzBuzz"
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            result = &"Fizz"
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            result = &"Buzz"
        }
        println!("{}", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note however that your first solution allocates, copies and drops the strings at each iteration, and that your second solution wastes resources converting `i` to string even when printing a predefined string. It would be better to either print directly inside the `if`, without going through `result`, or to use a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

Comment: @Jmb: Or even better, use the uninitialized variable trick: `let si;` before the `if` and then `si = i.to_string(); &si` inside ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2cf3db4b0552128aef78e54e9707afaa))