# Convert String to &str in Rust

Tags: string, rust, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `String` to an `&str`.  But the problem is that rust will always throw this error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `contents`
   --> src/utils.rs:111:5
    |
72  |         let contents = &contents[..];
    |                         -------- `contents` is borrowed here
...
111 |     result
    |     ^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

How do i convert the variable into an &str?

Comment: Just return a `String` it's what you want in 99.9% of all cases. See also [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str/74537374)

Comment: The goal of the code is to return a `Vec<&str>`.  I cant just return a string here.

Comment: Then you want to return `Vec<String>` you can't create references without an owner unless you leak memory.

Comment: Your code is way too incomplete to provide any specific help, all we can say is that you're trying to return a reference to a `String` which was created or moved in the current function, which is not allowed (ish, you could always leak the string after all). Either find a way not to do that, or change your return type to return the owned data.

Comment: I just made it return a vector of strings, and that fixed everything.

Comment: I would go with this rule of thumb - when you want to work on a string-like thing (function argument), use a `&str`.  When you want to _store_ a string-like thing, use a `String`.  Exceptions exist both ways, but it works quite a lot of the time.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was better to return `Vec<String>` then `Vec<&str>`.  That fixed my issue. Thanks to [cafce25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442760/cafce25) for giving the idea.

Comment: A safe rule of thumb if you're struggling with rust lifetimes is to write functions that take references and return values (so in this case, take `&str`s and return `String`s)